# Cannot access webpage by https

Tags: android, spark-java

When i remove this method

```
secure(keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword, null, null);
```

I can access my webpage: http://localhost:8080/index

when i add:

```
secure(keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword, null, null);
```

The webpage: https://localhost:8080/index doesn't display , connection failed, what i missed please?

Thank you.

Comment: Which webserver is running on your Android device?

Comment: This server Jetty server

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try is to change the port. Most browsers would attempt http over port 8080. Try adding this with your secure method:

```
port(443);
secure(keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword, null, null);
```

Then you will have to access it with https://localhost:443/index, of course. If this doesn't work, then you may have an issue with your keystore.

Comment: I try this, same problem, i create the keystore with this command: 'keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias some_alias -keystore test.jks -storepass pass_store -validity 365 -keysize 2048 -dname "cn=John_Doe,ou=TestOrgUnit,o=TestOrg,c=US"'